What is a real world use-case of explicitly capturing a variable rather than having an argument?
I've been reading up on lambdas, and I am wondering why it would be advantageous to explicitly capture a variable, either by value or by reference, rather than pass it to a lambda via the arguments.
I can imagine if there was a large list of variables outside the scope of a lambda that one would want to use. Not having to write out the arguments for them all by using [=]/[&] saves some typing. but I can't imagine a use-case for writing a lambda to handle complex logic requiring that many variables in the surrounding scope anyway.
And, for cases with a small capture list, what have you saved/accomplished by using a capture rather than an argument besides the tiniest bit of typing:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    int N = 2;
    
    auto less_than = [](int x, int y){ return x < y; };
    auto less_than_N = [N](int x) { return x < N; };
    
    bool result1 = less_than(4, N);
    bool result2 = less_than_N(4);
    
    std::cout << result1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << result2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Essentially, I'd like to know how captures are useful in a more general sense. I know how to use them, but not the cases in which they become useful for real world purposes. My experience using lambdas stems from wanting to quickly create a function "object" so that it can be passed to another method or function, or maybe stored in a map for look up later. I'm not seeing how captures help much in that context.

Sometimes, often they way I seem to write code, the value you captured will not be available later when you use the lambda.

@user4581301 So the capture grabs what is available in the scope in which it was declared, rather than in the scope in which it is used?

Sometimes you can't pass anything extra to the lambda, Imagine you call std::count_if with a lambda as the predicate. Another point, if you want to move capture then you have to explicitly do so.

@NathanOliver In that case, if you didn't use the capture you'd have to use std::bind or some such?

Yeah, which is just another way to capture.

Great! My question is answered. If you one of you wants to write it up to take credit, feel free. Either way, you both have my thanks!

Lot of reading between the lines to get your answer from that duplicate. Still looking for a better one. More good information here.

Can't add this as a duplicate because it is itself a duplicate, but I believe Anthony Williams' answer sums up your specific question better than what we've found so far.
